# How to make a finished portrait layout different in landscape mode

Tags: ios, layout, orientation, xcode8

Here's an image of what I'm trying to make.

[image]

I've already made the layout on the left, but as you see, the layout is different in landscape mode. So my question is, what do I do with my finished portrait layout, so that it looks like the image on the right, when in landscape mode?

Any suggestions would be a big help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Size Classes / Traits to accomplish this. In essence, you assign different constraints based on the device's width and height being Compact or Regular.

There is a good, clear article / Introduction to it here:

https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

After a quick read through it, I put your layout together, just as an exercise:

https://github.com/DonMag/AutoLayoutTraits

[image]